# Can I use multiple docker containers on a computer as Kubernetes worker nodes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to configure a Kubernetes cluster with only Docker containers without using vm on one machine. I think it will be, but I ask because it may not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting your question right you want to use Kubernetes on a physical box without using any hypervisor (no vm)

You can install minikube and use Kubernetes as below

`minikube start --vm-driver=none`

Answer (score 4):

Checkout Kubernetes In Docker - [kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind)
This is probably what you want.

Comment: Thank you. Let's install The description doesn't look much different from the usual Kubernetes.